# Rename only visible layers in illustrator javascript

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe-illustrator

Super noob question. I found a code that renames my top level layers as "Frame 1, Frame 2, etc..." How can I have the rename apply ONLY to visible layers? Second question is how do I rename only a selected layer (whether it visible or not) to "Frame 1" or whatever I choose and not affect any other layers in the document?

Here is the code.

```
    var doc = app.activeDocument;  

    idLayers(doc); // Rename layers  

    function idLayers(doc){  
        for(i=0;doc.layers.length>i;i++){  
            var currentLayer = doc.layers[i];  
            currentLayer.name= 'Frame  '+(i+1);  
        }  
}
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can all be easily found in the  [illustrator scripting reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/illustrator/sdk/CC2015/Illustrator%20Scripting%20Reference%20-%20JavaScript.pdf).

This script does both things you asked, just comment out the function call you don't want to run and put the layer prefix or name you want for the layer in the function call.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;  

idLayers("Frame "); // Rename visible layers 
renameSelectedLayer("Active"); // Rename active layers  

// Hidden layers will be skipped and not counted
function idLayers(prefix){ 
  var counter = 1; 
  for(i=0;doc.layers.length>i;i++){ 
    var currentLayer = doc.layers[i]; 

    // if layer is visible...
    if (currentLayer.visible) {
      currentLayer.name= prefix + counter;
      counter++;  
    }

  }  
}    

function renameSelectedLayer(layerName){ 
  doc.activeLayer.name = layerName
}
```

Comment: Works! Thank you very much!

Comment: No worries, glad to help. You should probably mark as answered though so it will go off the list of unanswered questions.